# How to get the message link of an embed in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to send an embed in discord, and then store the message link of the embed in a database. But in order to do that, I need a way to access the link to the embed. Is there any way to get the message link of a MessageEmbed object in discord.js? I've looked through the discord.js docs but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [message.url](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=url) to get the URL for a message

If your bot sends a message it can be used like this

```js
channel.send(embed).then(embedMessage => {
    const url = embedMessage.url
    // add to url database
});
```